# How to increment row values by 1 when inserting

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table called `LocationProduct` and its structure is as follows,

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 103         | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 104         | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 105         | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 100         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 101         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 102         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 103         | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 104         | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 105         | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now I need to increment `SortValue` column's value by one when I insert a new row. As an example,

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices(FkBranchId,FkServiceId,SortValue)
VALUES(1,106,1)
```

I need to update `FkLocationId = 1` related SortValue by one, I need the following output,

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 103         | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 104         | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 105         | 7         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 106         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Here you can see I updated each old records SortValue by one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one transaction first `UPDATE` the values then do the `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE branchservices
       SET sortvalue = sortvalue + 1
       WHERE sortvalue >= 1;

INSERT INTO branchservices
            (fkbranchid,
             fkserviceid,
             sortvalue)
            VALUES (1,
                    106,
                    1);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, can please look on this too. please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166993/how-to-increment-column-by-one-group-wise