# How to increment column by one group wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a table called `productLocation`, and its data structure as follows,  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1997/1)

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 103         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 104         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 105         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 100         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 101         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 102         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 103         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 104         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2            | 105         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3            | 100         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3            | 101         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3            | 102         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3            | 103         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 3            | 104         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

For each location have its own sorting order for products. But some of the products have **`0`** as the `SortValue`
Now I need to write a query to update `SortValue` as,

If I consider one location, `FkLocationId  = 1`

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 0         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 103         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 104         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 105         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

In the above data table, you can see, `FkProductId  = 100,101,102` have **`0`** as the `SortValue`. I need to update its `sortValue` as order by `FkProductId` descending order. I need to update its like

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

And also update the previous SortValue by one by one.

Then the complete output should be,

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| FkLocationId | FkProductId | SortValue |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 100         | 3         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 101         | 2         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 102         | 1         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 103         | 5         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 104         | 4         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1            | 105         | 6         |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Is this possible to do? I'm really confused about this, please help me to solve this. Thank you

**Updated:**

Suppose I have another table as product. And its data structure as follows,

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ProdcutId | SortValue |
+-----------+-----------+
| 100       | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 101       | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 107       | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 108       | 1         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 109       | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 110       | 6         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 111       | 5         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 112       | 4         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 113       | 3         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I also need to do same thing for this table as well, How can I do it

Expected Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ProdcutId | SortValue |
+-----------+-----------+
| 100       | 3         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 101       | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 107       | 1         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 108       | 4         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 109       | 5         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 110       | 9         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 111       | 8         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 112       | 7         |
+-----------+-----------+
| 113       | 6         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18) has a nifty little button called "Text to DDL". Please use it and [edit] your question with [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) sample data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I updated the question with SQL fiddle sir http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1997/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a sample query for you to check and use the same logic for your update process using CTE-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a64b7dc0b899b812e30e4c78369d753b)

**Important Note:** Update is a risky process and you should try with your test data first.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM #Temp B 
        WHERE B.FkLocationId = A.FkLocationId
        AND SortValue = 0
    ) Zero_Count,
    -- The above Zero count is a simple count of rows with 0
    -- for a specific FkLocationId. This is for adding to other 
    -- rows where there are already value in column SortValue. The logic
    -- is simple, the number of row with 0 in column SortValue, 
    -- should be add to existing value where there is value not equal 0.
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FkLocationId ORDER BY SortValue ASC, FkProductId DESC) RN
    -- ROW_NUMBER is simply creating the Number you should replace 0 by.
    -- As you are looking for 1 to start for the MAX FkProductId with 0,
    -- I applied DESC order on that column
    FROM #Temp A
) 

UPDATE A
SET A.SortValue = 
CASE 
    WHEN A.SortValue = 0 THEN B.RN 
    -- RN is created in such way, so that you can directly 
    -- Replace your value in column SortValue by RN if SortValue = 0 
    ELSE A.SortValue + B.Zero_Count
    -- IF SortValue contains already value > 0, 
    -- You need to just increment the value with Number 
    -- of rows is there with value 0. I have calculated that value
    -- by a sub query in the CTE you can check.
END
FROM  #Temp A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.FkLocationId = B.FkLocationId
AND A.FkProductId = B.FkProductId


SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

> Just use your "table_name" where I have used #temp

Comment: Its better if you can explain each part sir in query.

Comment: @Adam, I have added some comments in the script. Check that helped or not. If more clarification required, I can explain.

Comment: Sir I added another part to my question as **Updated** Can you please explain how can I do same thing for that table. So it will be easy to take an idea for me. please give me an answer to updated part

Comment: You can use the same query for this as well. The only difference is you have no FkLocationId  column this time. Just avoid the part of query where I have used column FkLocationId  as ref.

Comment: @Adam check this DEMO - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62977a37b3e7f02a519d4befd2088b09

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as
(select FkLocationId, FkProductId, SortValue,
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by FkLocationId order by sortvalue,FkProductId desc) new_sort_value
from productLocation where FkLocationId =1  --and SortValue =0
)

update pl SET
pl.SortValue = c.new_sort_value
from productLocation pl inner join cte c
on pl.FkLocationId = c.FkLocationId and pl.FkProductId = c.FkProductId

Select * from productLocation where FkLocationId =1 order by FkProductId
```

The core of the approach taken by me is based row_number window function, which partitions data over fkproductid sorted by sortvalue and fkproductid in descending manner.

There are 2 queries involved, although could have been done is single, but for simplicity's sake i have used common table expression (cte)

CTE derived from query one is used as joining table in second update query.

I have left much to self exploration, remember its imperative to think in term of sets.